# Using variable outside a class in PHP

Tags: php

Assuming that I have 3 PHP files:

1. index.php:

   ```
   require('config.php');
   require('connect_db.php');
   new connect_db();
   ```
2. config.php:

   ```
   $config['db_host'] = 'localhost';
   $config['db_username'] = 'root';
   $config['db_password'] = '';
   $config['db_name'] = 'my_db';
   ```
3. connect_db.php:

   ```
   class connect_db{
       function __construct(){
          $this->conn = new mysqli($config['db_host'], $config['db_username'], $config['db_password'], $config['db_name']);
       }
   }
   ```

When I run above codes, I meet an error: `"Undefined variable: config in...."`.
My question is: How can I use the $config variable inside "connect_db" class without including `config.php` file in connect_db.php file.

Thanks!

Comment: Pass your `$config` variable as an argument to your class constructor. See the PHP reference on [constructors](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, pass the $config variable into the constructor of the class.

```
new connect_db($config);

class connect_db{
    function __construct($config){
       $this->conn = new mysqli($config['db_host'], $config['db_username'], $config['db_password'], $config['db_name']);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add this line near the top of `config.php` and inside the `__construct()` function:

```
global $config;
```

Then they will be shared.

I would recommend choosing a better variable name than `$config` though. Perhaps something like `$database_configuration`, so you are less likely to use the same variable name in two places.